# if I write a https program with libcurl, which CA cert should I download?

Tags: ssl, https, libcurl

I write a program to verify this website:

`www.alipay.com`

which root CA cert should I download from VeriSign, Inc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one:

https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/library/VERISIGN/ALL_OTHER/RapidSSL%20Intermediate/RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem

Or this one from mozilla:

https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1

Comment: Beware not to use certificates that are explicitly distrusted in the Mozilla list. (Curl's `caextract` script seems to do this correctly.)

Answer (score 4):

The curl project itself provides the Mozilla bundle converted to PEM if you'd like that:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html