# OpenSSL reasonable default for trusted CA certificates?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Is there a way to set up an OpenSSL context (`SSL_CTX`) with a reasonable set of trusted CA certificates *without* distributing them myself? I don't want the responsibility of keeping them up to date. IMO any modern operating system should provide "get me the trusted CA certs" as a service, but I don't know if that's actually the case.

I don't mind writing this code three times (once for Windows, once for Mac OS X, and once for Linux), but I'd prefer to cap it at that. In particular, I'd rather not try to write code that snoops around looking for what browsers are installed and trying to extract their trusted certificates. (Apparently it's [easy to get this very wrong](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2012/01/30/mozillaroots.html).)

The answer for recent versions of Linux seems to be to call `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` with `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` (if that file exists).

Are there simple answers for Windows and Mac OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`curl`'s script](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) that converts the list from Mozilla (from [Curl's maintainer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024031/372643)). According to [its code](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl), it seems to check whether the certificate is trusted or not before including it.

Answer (score 12):

Here's what I ended up doing:

On Windows: get the certificates from the Windows `"ROOT"` certificate store using `CertOpenSystemStore`, loop over them using `CertEnumCertificatesInStore`, grab the X509-encoded raw certificate from the `pbCertEncoded` field of the `CERT_CONTEXT`, create an OpenSSL `X509` structure using `d2i_X509`, and add it to the OpenSSL certificate store using `X509_STORE_add_cert`. The Windows functions are all available from `crypt32.dll`.

On Mac OS X: get the certificates from the `"/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain"` keychain using `SecKeychainOpen`, create an iterator for the certificates in the keychain using `SecKeychainSearchCreateFromAttributes`, iterate using `SecKeychainSearchCopyNext`, get the raw X509 certificate using `SecItemExport`, create an OpenSSL certificate using `d2i_X509`, and add it to the OpenSSL store using `X509_STORE_add_cert`. The Mac functions are available from `/Systems/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security`.

A better approach might be to create an OpenSSL `X509_STORE` with a callback that uses OS functions to verify an individual root cert, rather than copying all of them over, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: @proteneer, the code is now part of the Racket openssl library here: https://github.com/plt/racket/tree/master/racket/collects/openssl/private

Comment: The Windows code described above is available in actual code here: https://curl.haxx.se/mail/meet-2017-03/0030.html

Comment: Update: On Mac OS, it seems like it might be better to use `SecTrustCopyAnchorCertificates` rather than opening the system keychain and iterating through it. The remaining steps are the same.

Answer (score 6):

On OS X, you can get information on the certificates trusted by the user from the user's Keychain. Here is a link containing some very good information on collecting that info using Cocoa:

[Get Certificates in Keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767957/get-certificates-in-keychain)

If Cocoa is not an ok dependency for your needs, and you want to do everything straight from the command line, you could use the `certtool` utility- see `man certtool` and other online documentation to learn about it. To list all certificates in the user's login keychain, you might do:

```
certtool y k=login.keychain
```

Or to get a list of the built-in trusted system roots:

```
certtool y k=/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
```

and maybe

```
certtool y k=/System/Library/Keychains/SystemCACertificates.keychain
```

I'm sure there are other ways to get at that information using system interfaces as well.

On the Linux side, yes, `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is the right way to go. That file will exist on Debian derivatives (inc. Ubuntu variants) when the `ca-certificates` package is installed, and I'm not sure how to get it there properly on redhat-based systems.

Comment: Do you know how `certtool` behaves for certificates that are explicitly flagged as "never trust", though?

Comment: I don't think certtool will show anything regarding trust levels; you'd want to query for trustiness using a different mechanism. Try `man security` for one good way, if you're really into using the command line tools for this.

Comment: See also MacPorts' certsync utility (https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/security/certsync/#files, the actual code is in `files/certsync.m`), which also exports the trusted roots into a file and does pay attention to the trust flags (by not exporting them).